# Get campaign subject line with mailchimp API v3.0

Tags: json, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I ve used this function to get a specific campaign's details using Mailchimp API v3.0.

```
function mc_insert_campaign($email, $apikey, $server) {

    $apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxmyAPI';
    $camp_id = '1753ef2cce';


    $auth = base64_encode( 'user:'. $apikey );
    $data = array(
        'apikey'        => $apikey,
        'id' => $camp_id
        );
    $json_data = json_encode($data);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://'.$server.'.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns/'. $camp_id);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Basic '. $auth));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
//    if ($debug) {
//        var_dump($result);
//    }
    $json = json_decode($result);

    $camp_type = $json->{'type'};

    echo $camp_type;

}
```

So far it works ok for me since that I 'm taking the Campaign Type.
But I need to extract the subject line too.

As I read in MC API documentation the json answer it looks like :

```
{
  "id": "42694e9e57",
  "type": "regular",
  "create_time": "2015-09-15T14:40:36+00:00",
  "archive_url": ".....",
  "status": "save",
  "emails_sent": 0,
  "send_time": "",
  "content_type": "template",
  "recipients": {
    "list_id": "57afe96172",
    "segment_text": ""
  },
  "settings": {
    "subject_line": "I have a rice crispy treat watermelon farm.",
    "title": "Freddie's Jokes Vol. 1",
    "from_name": "Freddie",
    "reply_to": "freddie@freddiesjokes.com",
    "use_conversation": false,
    "to_name": "",
    "folder_id": 0,
    "authenticate": true,
    "auto_footer": false,
    "inline_css": false,
    "auto_tweet": false,
    "fb_comments": false,
    "timewarp": false,
    "template_id": 100,
    "drag_and_drop": true
  }, .........
```

I have tried something like

```
$camp_type = $json->{'settings'}{'type'};
```

but it didn't worked. What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance..

Comment: where do you get the campaign id from?  yours seems to be 10 alpha-numeric characters and mine seems to be 7 numeric digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution... I suppose it is very basic but I m posting it anyway just in case someone interested!

The solution is: $camp_subject_line = $json->settings->{'subject_line'}.

Thanx anyway!